# How to structure views for admin layout in laravel blade?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

The goal is to create an admin area in my laravel project. I have a question about how to structure views and controllers to create the admin layout using laravel components.

Say I have a single controller (`app/Http/Controllers/CategoryController.php`) at the moment:

```
class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('category.index');
    }
}
```

View (`resources/views/categories/index.blade.php`):

```
<x-app-layout>
    Categories Index Page
</x-app-layout>
```

The base layout is defined in `resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php`.

Functionality that is inside `CategoryController` is for admins only. I want to create an admin layout that inherits from the base layout. The category views then go inside the admin layout. The admin layout has a sidebar on the left with a navigation. The navigation points to controllers like `CategoryController` and `UserController`. The admin layout will expose various admin functionality.

[image]

What I've tried:

`views/admin/admin.blade.php`:

```
<x-app-layout>
    <h1>TEST</h1>
    {{$slot}}
</x-app-layout>
```

and `views/admin/categories/index.blade.php`:

```
<x-admin>
    Categories Index Page
</x-admin>
```

Error:

> Unable to locate a class or view for component [admin].

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? How should one structure the views for suche use case?

Comment: Does it have to be components? You could create a `resources/views/layouts/admin.blade.php` that `@extends('layouts.app')`

Comment: @brombeer nope, does not have to be components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `resources/views/layouts/admin.blade.php` that looks something like this:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
  <div class="navigation">
    ...YourNavbar...
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    @yield('content')
  </div>
@overwrite
```

(Edit the code inside to match how you want your navbar/content to look like)

Now your `resources/views/categories/index.blade.php` should use `@extends('layouts.admin')` instead of `@extends('layouts.app')`

Edit: this is assuming your `app.blade.php` has a `@yield('content')` to show content

Comment: If someone is looking for a solution using components: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-6-from-scratch/episodes/61.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because you have to create the component file 'AdminLayout.php' for your admin layout in: /app/View/Components and then use `<x-admin-layout>` in your view files